# What legal instruments in the Russian Empire criminalised teaching peasants to read?

Tags: russia, education, crime, ukraine, russian-empire

When he was 17 - and he was born in 1867 so this was after the 1861 abolition of serfdom - Boris Sidis was jailed in the Ukraine, then in the Russian Empire, for the crime of teaching peasants to read and write. (Source: [Sarah Sidis](https://www.sidis.net/methods.htm); for his age, [here](http://www.berdichev.org/boris_sidis.htm).)

Under what law was such activity a crime? When did it become a crime?

Comment: Did you look at the Wikipedia article on [Sidis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boris_Sidis). It says he was arrested under the [May Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/May_Laws).

Comment: Timing would fit (antisemitic laws following assassination of A2), and B Sidis's parents were Jewish, but there's 0 about the ML in material at sidis.net about his imprisonment. "The Czarist police began watching the boys when their unusual behavior of teaching peasants became known." If he was jailed under ML then what was the charge? "(H)e was told he had a chance to go home if he would fill in the details of what the mvt had been all about... Education was considered a political mvt because it interfered w the social hierarchy that supported the political structure of Russia at this time."

Comment: Teaching peasants to read was definitely not a crime (there were numerous parish schools doing exactly this; private individuals also have done this, Leo Tolstoy is one of the most famous examples). The linked article simply misstates the reason of arrest in the case of Sidis, that's all.

Comment: I am also very skeptical about the claim that Sidis was arrested and imprisoned under "May Laws." Most likely, the person who wrote this confused the "May Laws" with the "Emergency Laws" passed at about the same time, see [here](https://www.encyclopedia.com/history/encyclopedias-almanacs-transcripts-and-maps/temporary-regulations#:~:text=In%20response%20to%20the%20assassination,that%20had%20previously%20been%20enforced.) According to these laws, **anybody** deemed suspicious by the police could be arrested  and imprisoned for up to 3 months and then exiled for up to 5 years.

Comment: [According to his wife](https://www.sidis.net/methods.htm), he was sentenced to an indefinite term in prison. [Here](http://www.berdichev.org/boris_sidis.htm) is a reference to a Czarist ukase against teaching the peasants to read. There could have been a local order.

Comment: @tell Interesting. [An article in a Russian journal](https://doaj.org/article/9b18f1d5284641298f09b5e4ae8a6613) repeats the claim about getting arrested for teaching peasants, and references the [Dictionary Of American Biography Volume 17](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.425644/page/n163/mode/2up)... which actually states that Sidis was arrested as *a student*, along with other students. If that info (again, unsourced) is correct - it is possible that they were arrested for concealing their nationality to bypass quotas on school acceptance imposed by May Laws.